# SPARX EA: Exporting Requirements to Word

Tags: modeling, enterprise, enterprise-architect, requirements

I'm working with SPARX Enterprise Architect (version 11.0), and as part of a larger model I am modeling requirements. I've created a bunch of Requirement entities, but I would like to export them as some sort of table into a word document.

Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried using the "templates" in the past, but they're rather complicated and they spit out a lot more than what I'm really trying to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Word document out of native EA, document templates is all you've got. However, you can export model data as CSV, import it into Excel and from there to Word.

There are several ways to export CSV data from EA, ranked from hardest-but-most-reusable to easisest-but-most-manual:

1. Create a CSV import/export profile and run it (project browser context menu -- Import/Export -- CSV Import/Export).
2. Create a search which finds the elements, run it and copy from the search results window into Excel. The search defines which columns are created.
3. Place the elements in a diagram, switch to list view (diagram context menu, or diagram main menu -- Show Diagram As -- List View) and copy from that. The columns can be selected by right-clicking a column header.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Create a document generation template, which you can tailor so it only reports what you want it to.
- use the model search and copy/paste the contents into a .CSV file. If you create an SQL search you can define exactly which fields are shown int he search results.
- Create a CSV export profile where you define which fields to export in which order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied with the options offered by Enterprise Architect, you might want to give "[eaDocx](http://www.eadocx.com/home-page/introducing-eadocx)" a try.

> eaDocX™ is the Microsoft Word and Excel document generator Add-In for Enterprise Architect